# I have an error with video settings when creating a video from an array of images in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, video

so I've been having a problem for a while. When creating a video file from an array of images, I've been getting errors linking with the video settings

```
let paths = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let documentsURL = images[0]
    let videoWriter: AVAssetWriter = AVAssetWriter(URL: documentsURL, fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie, error: nil)

    var videoSettings: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()

    videoSettings = [
        AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
        AVVideoWidthKey: 1080,
        AVVideoHeightKey: 1920
    ]

    var exportPath: NSString = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingFormat("/video.mov")
    var exportUrl: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(exportPath as String)

    var exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoSettings, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exporter.outputURL = exportUrl

    exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
        library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(exportURL, completionBlock: { (assetURL:NSURL!, error:NSError?) -> Void in
             })
    })
```

so In that block of code which should create the video file from the array called "images", the line

```
var exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoSettings, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
```

gives an error at "videoSettings" but I don't understand why this is happening. The error is "cannot convert value of type 'NSDictionary' to expected argument type 'AVAsset'"

The line

```
let videoWriter: AVAssetWriter = AVAssetWriter(URL: documentsURL, fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie, error: nil)
```

also gives an error at 'AVAssetWriter'

the error is "cannot invoke initializer of type 'AVAssetWriter' with an argument list of type (URL: UIImage, fileType: String, error:_)'"

Please can someone help with this problem, Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, I've looked through the problem and tried different ways but none seem to do the trick

Comment: Okay, please let me know if you come up with a solution. It's frustrating I'm looking for a solution to the exact same problem. There is no answer at all in Swift for this issue, I've looked everywhere! I'll let you know if I find the solution :)

Comment: Yeah will do and thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Sam Ive found a Github page which converts a string of a UIImage into a video, however Im using UIImage and dont know how to convert to a string. this is it - https://github.com/justinlevi/imagesToVideo